# Regular expression : match a string that end with any number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get regular expression that give me string ending with any number.

Example :

Input Strings : [ test-1, test-2, test-200, test-34dd, test-sdfsd, test-4 ]

output(matching string) should be like :

[test-1, test-2, test-200, test-4]

Comment: Why you put them all in a list?

Comment: `^.*?\d$` would do this job.

Comment: just for anybody understanding.........

Comment: if i use ^test-*?\d$ give me correct output

Comment: Yep, could modify the regex to match the strings which starts with test and has a number at the last.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match the strings which starts with the string `test` and ends with a number,

```
^test-.*?\d$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nW4yD9/6)

Comment: Why there `?`, the same result with: `^test-.*\d$`

Comment: @Rimas regex engine needs to be backtracked if i use the above regex.`.*` matches upto the last. Once it finds the following `\d`, the engine bactracks and tries to match the digit followed by the end of line anchor.

Answer (score 2):

Match any word followed by dash and any digit:

```
^(\w+)-(\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want more than one match per line, you have to have /g option.

Also, you want word boundaries iso string boundaries.

Please check following solution:

```
\b\w+-\d+\b
```

Play around, and check explanation on:

http://regex101.com/r/sO3dZ0/1